# Converting List to Dictionary using JsonConvert.SerializeObject but keeping key as int?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, json.net

Is there a way to keep a key as an `int` when converting the list to a dictionary using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`.

I'm calling the following code from my asp.net mvc web app:

```
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.Fields.Select(f => new
{
    Id = f.Id,
    Name = f.Name,
    Type = f.Type,
    ...
}).ToDictionary(x => x.Id));
```

The code above works well, but it converts my Id field to a string instead of keeping it in its original type i.e. `int`. Is there a way to keep it as an `int` so that I don't have to convert the key to an `int` every time I have to access my dictionary from the client side when using javascript.

I know I could just write a quick function to get me the relevant item and only convert the key in that function but I thought I'd ask as keeping the key type in its original format seems cleaner and the right thing to do.

Thanks.

Comment: any particular reason you're doing manual serialisation? If you're returning this data to the client (browser) then MVC can serialise it automatically for you.

Comment: I'm setting a Javascript variable when my page is rendered (`fields = @Html.Raw(@Model.ClientData);` via Razor so that I can access some of this information via the client side and saving me having to make a separate request as this data is needed as my page is created.

Comment: Just to be clear, my @Model.ClientData is the function that's calling the code mentioned in the original question.

Comment: Can't you just do `this.Fields.Select(f => new
{
    Id = f.Id })` and serialise that? Why do you need to first select (and then immediately discard) the other fields if you're just after the ID, and why do you need to turn it into a Dictionary?